# Access WooCommerce functions inside custom class in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a plugin for wordpress using woocommerce.
I create a class Product which will give me all the metadata concerning a product from woocommerce, but I can't use woocommerce inside my functions:

```
<?php
class Product {
    //PROPERTIES
    public function __construct($sku) {
        $this->sku = $sku;
    }

    public function GetWooMeta($sku) {
        global $woocommerce;
        //Get product ID with SKU.
        $productID = $woocommerce->wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
        //Get Product object with ID.
        //$product_object = $woocommerce->wc_get_product( $productID );
        
        $product_meta = array();
        
        array_push($product_meta, 
        $woocommerce->$product_object->wp_get_attachment_image_url( $woocommerce>$product_object->get_image_id(), 'full' ),
        $woocommerce->$product_object->get_name(),
        $woocommerce->$product_object->get_price(), $woocommerce->get_permalink( $productID 
        ));
        return $product_meta;
    }
    $product1 = new Product ( 'GFI286260002I' );

    echo $product1->GetWooMeta( $product1->sku );
?>
```

This is the error thrown by wordpress:

```
//Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function wc_get_product_id_by_sku() on null
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Product {
    //PROPERTIES
    public function __construct($sku) {
        $this->sku = $sku;
    }

    public function GetWooMeta($sku) {
        global $woocommerce;
        //Get product ID with SKU.
         $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'product' );
         $productID = $data_store->get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
        //$productID = $woocommerce->wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
        //Get Product object with ID.
        //$product_object = $woocommerce->wc_get_product( $productID );
        
        $product_meta = array();
        
        array_push($product_meta, 
        $woocommerce->$product_object->wp_get_attachment_image_url( $woocommerce>$product_object->get_image_id(), 'full' ),
        $woocommerce->$product_object->get_name(),
        $woocommerce->$product_object->get_price(), $woocommerce->get_permalink( $productID 
        ));
        return $product_meta;
    }
    //$product1 = new Product ( 'GFI286260002I' );
    $product = new WC_Product('GFI286260002I');
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    echo $product1->GetWooMeta( $sku );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was declaring my class outside of any functions and seems that wordpress didn't load Woocommerce first , which was the error.